# No instance for (Random (IO a0)) arising from a use of `randomR' in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to generate a random number using randomR but it is showing an error which I am not getting.

My code:

```
randomMessage :: IO String
randomMessage = do
    index<-fst $ randomR (0,9) (mkStdGen 66)
    --let index = randomRIO (1,10)
    return ("This is message " ++ show index)
```

```
Error:
app\Main.hs:63:18: error:
* No instance for (Random (IO a0)) arising from a use of `randomR'
* In the second argument of `($)', namely
`randomR (0, 9) (mkStdGen 66)'
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
index <- fst $ randomR (0, 9) (mkStdGen 66)
In the expression:
do index <- fst $ randomR (0, 9) (mkStdGen 66)
return ("This is message " ++ show index)
index<-fst $ randomR (0,9) (mkStdGen 66)
                     ^^^^^^^
```

Kindly let me know the solution

Comment: in addtion to @jpmarinier, you can use `index <- randomRIO (0, 9)` if you are working in the IO monad

Comment: Function randomR returns a non-monadic, “pure” value, and you are using symbol “<-” which is about extracting pure values from monadic actions. You can remove the type mismatch like this: let index = fst $ randomR (0,9) (mkStdGen 66) . But a better alternative is probably to use `getStdGen` so the system chooses the seed for you.

Comment: Hi I tried both of your solutions, but it didnt working yet.

Comment: `let index = randomRIO (1, 10)` is wrong because you *aren't* using `<-` to "extract" the number from the `IO` action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`randomRIO` returns an `IO` action from which you can extract a value.

```
randomMessage :: IO String
randomMessage = do
    index <- randomRIO (1,10::Int)
    return ("This is message " ++ show index)
```

A type annotation is necessary to indicate what type of value `index` will be, so that the correct `Show` instance may be selected.

---

`randomR` returns a tuple consisting of a random value and a new random number generator.

```
randomMessage :: IO String
randomMessage = do
    let index = fst $ randomR (0,9 :: Int) (mkStdGen 66)
    return ("This is message " ++ show index)
```

This "works", but it won't be very random, as the exact same seed is used for every call. (There's also no reason for it to return an IO action. `randomR` is pure, the idea being that its return value contains what you need to generate another random number.) You can use `getStdGen`, but that's still the same random number generator each time you call the function.

```
randomMessage :: IO String
randomMessage = do
    (index, _) <- randomR (0,9 :: Int) <$> getStdGen
    return ("This is message " ++ show index)
```

To fix this, you need to use `setStdGen` on the *other* value in the tuple produced by `randomR`.

```
randomMessage :: IO String
randomMessage = do
    (index, nextGen) <- randomR (0,9 :: Int) <$> getStdGen
    setStdGen nextGen
    return ("This is message " ++ show index)
```

(If I understand the definition of `randomIO` correctly, this is essentially what it does: uses `randomR` to generate a new number and update the system generator. One important difference: it gets a random number and updates the system generator *atomically*, so that anyone else trying to use the system generator will use the generator produced here by `randomR`, not the same one that `getStdGen` initially provided.)